# OSX Authentication/Connection Issues

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-yosemite

I've posted this on community.ubnt.com too

HI all,

I recently redeployed our UniFi system and upgraded to 3.2.9 using FreeRADIUS for authentication

We have a fleet of various Toshiba and Lenovos that aren't affected by this issue (that we know of)

There are 12 MacBooks (mixture of Pro and Air) in service, some of these frequently, lose authentication and fail to reauth until being disconnected and reconnecting

The following is from one of the MacBook Pros (Early 2011 8. 3)  running 10.10.1

```
22/01/2015 13:41:42.000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1 Auth result for: 06:27:22:d5:e8:56 Auth request tx failed
22/01/2015 13:41:42.000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1 Auth result for: 2a:a4:3c:95:74:f8 MAC AUTH succeeded
22/01/2015 13:41:42.000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
22/01/2015 13:41:42.000 kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid 2a:a4:3c:95:74:f8
```

Has anyone seen anything similar in their environments with UniFi or is this one of the pesky OSX WiFi bugs?